# C++ Operator Overload. Why can't I prototype it properly

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This may seem like a really dumb question, but I've been researching and taking examples for the last hour and have yet to find the explanation, so I might as well ask here while I keep searching.

Why does this work and compile properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Fraccao{
    
   
    int denominador;
    
    
public:
     int numerador;
    Fraccao(int N = 0, int D = 1);
    void ChangeND(int N, int D);
    Fraccao operator*(Fraccao const &Frac){
        
        Fraccao FTemp;
        FTemp.numerador = this->numerador * Frac.numerador;
        FTemp.denominador = this->denominador * Frac.denominador;
        return FTemp;
        
    }
    
};

int main(){
    
    Fraccao F1(1, 2);
    Fraccao F2(3);
    Fraccao F3(3, 4);
    
    F1 = F2*F3;
    cout << F1.numerador;
    
}

Fraccao::Fraccao(int N, int D){
    
    numerador = N;
    if(D > 0){
        denominador = D;
    }else{
        denominador = 1;
    }
    cout << "Fraccao " << numerador << "/" << denominador << " criada." << endl;
}

void Fraccao::ChangeND(int N, int D){
    
    numerador = N;
    if(D > 0){
        denominador = D;
        
    }else{
        denominador = 1;
    }
    
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


class Fraccao{
    
   
    int denominador;
    
    
public:
     int numerador;
    Fraccao(int N = 0, int D = 1);
    void ChangeND(int N, int D);
    Fraccao operator*(Fraccao const &Frac);
    
};

int main(){
    
    Fraccao F1(1, 2);
    Fraccao F2(3);
    Fraccao F3(3, 4);
    
    F1 = F2*F3;
    cout << F1.numerador;
    
}

Fraccao::Fraccao(int N, int D){
    
    numerador = N;
    if(D > 0){
        denominador = D;
    }else{
        denominador = 1;
    }
    cout << "Fraccao " << numerador << "/" << denominador << " criada." << endl;
}

void Fraccao::ChangeND(int N, int D){
    
    numerador = N;
    if(D > 0){
        denominador = D;
        
    }else{
        denominador = 1;
    }
    
}

Fraccao::operator *(const Fraccao& Frac){
        
        Fraccao FTemp;
        FTemp.numerador = this->numerador * Frac.numerador;
        FTemp.denominador = this->denominador * Frac.denominador;
        return FTemp;
        
    }
```

The problem I appear to be getting on the second iteration of code is that: If I move the operator overload to outside the class it fails to work despite the prototype.

Comment: You are missing the return type in your operator definition: ```Fraccao::operator *(const Fraccao& Frac){``` should be ```Fraccao Fraccao::operator *(const Fraccao& Frac){```

Comment: Like this `Fraccao Fraccao::operator *(const Fraccao& Frac){`

Comment: But it's better to define `operator*` outside of the class `Fraccao operator*(const Fraccao& x, const Fraccao& y){`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: @StefanoBuora OMG thank you so much, I actually tried that but I did it like Fraccao & Fraccao::operator*(const Fraccao& Frac), so I guess my mistake on adding the "&" messed it up.

Comment: @john thank you so much, I actually tried that but like I pointed to someone else I mistaken myself by adding Fraccao & Fraccao.

Comment: @john I'm assuming you're talking about operator overloading globally and then make it friend? Still learning this part of programming, I'll look into your link, thanks.

Comment: @user215272 Yes that's right. If you make operator* part of a class then (in some circumstances) the compiler will treat the left and right hand sides differently. But if you make it global they always get treated the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return type in your operator definition:

```
Fraccao::operator *(const Fraccao& Frac){
```

should be

```
Fraccao Fraccao::operator *(const Fraccao& Frac){
```